# iOS7 - Game Center Integration

Tags: ios7, game-center

I spent all day searching for a tutorial on how to integrate Game Center into my iPhone app with no luck. I found few of them but they are either incomplete or obsolete.

```
1. I need a tutorial or documentation or any working source code.
2. Do I absolutly have to add my app in iTunes Connect during dev/test phases?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some documentation about GameCenter that should get you started: [GameCenter Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

And yes, you absolutely have to add your game to iTC during development as well as prepare all your leaderboards and achievements (if any). If your game isn't completed yet, I have found it useful to just add any screenshots to iTunes Connect until you finish. If you don't have any previous apps, simply put in any image of the correct size, same goes for the app icon.

Hope this helps!